# Access a Datagrid in a Rowdetailtemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

I've created a Datagrid in a Datagrid.RowDetailsTemplate and I would like use `Items.refresh` on it when I click on a button created outside of my Datagrid.

I can't find a way to access this function for datagrid_Detail with the button button_refreshDetail.
Here is my code :

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="618" Margin="10,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1472" AutoGenerateColumns="False" LoadingRowDetails="datagrid_LoadingRowDetails" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="a" Binding="{Binding a}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_Detail" ItemsSource="{Binding b}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="datagrid_Detail_SelectionChanged" MouseLeftButtonUp="datagrid_Detail_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="c" Binding="{Binding c, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="d" Binding="{Binding d, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="e" x:Name="combobox_e"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="f" x:Name="combobox_f"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="g" Binding="{Binding g, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="h" x:Name="combobox_h"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="i" x:Name="combobox_i"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="45" Header="j">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="j.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="button_refreshDetail" Content="button_refreshDetail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="129,697,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" Click="button_refreshDetail"/>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use that collection named "b" in order to alter the items?

If the binding is well configured and by that i mean :

- b is an `ObservableCollection`

and every custom data type in your collection

- implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

you should be able to update the properties of each object or add/remove items from the collection and the view will be updated with no other extra code.

At least this is something I would do. Maybe i am not understanding very well your refreshing scenario.

Comment: My scenario is : 
- I sort a column of my datagrid_Detail
- I update my data
- My data are updated but the datagrid dispay isn't because of the sorting..

Answer (score 0):

Use `ICollectionView` and `SortDescription` to sort `DataGrid`. It may not be a good idea to access `datagrid_Detail`, but manipulate the underlying data instead.